# Detour on winsock recv doesn't return anything

Tags: c++, dll, detours

I injected a dll into a server because I needed to block some bad packets that the server isn't discarding.

Snippet from my code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "detours.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Mswsock.lib")

(...)

int (WINAPI *pRecv)(SOCKET s, char* buf, int len, int flags) = recv;
int WINAPI MyRecv(SOCKET s, char* buf, int len, int flags);

(...)

AllocConsole();
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);

DetourTransactionBegin();
DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)pRecv, MyRecv);
if(DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR)
    cout << "[" << MyRecv << "] successfully detoured." << endl;
```

and for testing purposes I'm just printing the data out.

```
int WINAPI MyRecv(SOCKET s, char* buf, int len, int flags)
{

    cout << "[ RECV " << len << " ] ";
    for ( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) 
    {
         printf( "%02x ", unsigned char (buf[i]) );
    }
    printf( "\n" );

    return pRecv(s, buf, len, flags);
 }
```

Now I hooked it and it displays `[ address ] successfully detoured.`.
I guess everything is hooked and working.

Now I go to the client and start sending packets.
For example I log in, now this sends a packet to the server.
And I was successful in logging in so the server should've recieved the packet I have sent.

Now I check the console hooked to the `server` and nothing gets printed.
Which is odd, So I tried hooking WPE_PRO on the server and started communicating to with the client again. Now I found out that even WPE can't log the packets.

How is this possible? Why is this happening?

I'm trying to build a packet logger/filter on the server to keep bad packets out.
Hackers are using packets to crash our servers.

Info on the application I'm trying to hook:

```
It works like a relay server. It receives info from the client then sends it to the right server inside the internal network.

So Client <-> `Application` <-> Servers
So what I'm trying to hook is the Application .
```

---

*UPDATE*

Tried setting a breakpoint on the `recv()`, `WSArecv()` function and it doesn't break.

```
Address  Ordinal Name                        Library 
-------  ------- ----                        ------- 
004121A8 23      socket                      WS2_32  
004121A4 20      sendto                      WS2_32  
004121E8 3       closesocket                 WS2_32  
0041219C 9       htons                       WS2_32  
004121A0 17      recvfrom                    WS2_32  
004121E4 111     WSAGetLastError             WS2_32  
004121E0 115     WSAStartup                  WS2_32  
004121DC 11      inet_addr                   WS2_32  
004121D8         WSAIoctl                    WS2_32  
004121D4         WSAConnect                  WS2_32  
004121D0 22      shutdown                    WS2_32  
004121CC 12      inet_ntoa                   WS2_32  
004121C8 2       bind                        WS2_32  
004121C4 8       htonl                       WS2_32  
004121B4 16      recv                        WS2_32  
004121BC         WSASocketA                  WS2_32  
004121B8 19      send                        WS2_32  
004121B0         WSAAccept                   WS2_32  
004121AC 13      listen                      WS2_32  
004121C0 21      setsockopt                  WS2_32
```

Only these dll are being imported, when I checked the PE:

```
pdh.dll
WS2_32.dll
KERNEL32.dll
USER32.dll
GDI32.dll
WINMM.dll
```

---

*UPDATE*

Just to test if my code works, I hooked the DLL to the client and yes the packets got logged/printed. Confirms that my code works. Hmmmm.

---

*UPDATE*

Also tried to detour the ff.

```
int ( WINAPI *pSend )( SOCKET s, const char *buf, int len, int flags ) = send;
int ( WINAPI *pRecv )( SOCKET s, char *buf, int len, int flags ) = recv;
int ( WINAPI *pRecvFrom )( SOCKET s, char *buf, int len, int flags, sockaddr *from, int *fromlen ) = recvfrom;
int ( WINAPI *pWSARecvEx )( SOCKET s, char *buf, int len, int *flags ) = WSARecvEx;
```

and still nothing.

---

*UPDATE*

So I used `wireshark` and saw the packets passing through.
I've been debugging the program all day setting breakpoints on all winsock calls and still got nothing.

Comment: Have you tried hooking WSARecv ?